# Simple remote outdoor light switch that fits in a receptical box

Tags: lamp, motion-sensor

Upfront warning - I am pretty sure I am lacking the nomenclature to ask this succinctly.

I am installing an outdoor lamp with a store bought motion detector on a post about 30ft from the house. In addition to the motion sensor, I would like to be able to turn the lamp on from the house remotely. Everything will be wired inside a standard outdoor receptacle box with just a faceplate and some weather sealing.

I am pretty sure I know how to wire it in concept, but **what is the best 'thing' to use for something like this?**

It would be something that would:

1. powered inline with standard home electricity wiring
2. Have a remote that can reach 30ft through a wall
3. Perform a simple open/closed circuit operation
4. Fit inside a single gang outdoor receptacle box

I have been fighting trying to google for this but I think I just don't have the correct language to find what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You could run 3-conductor wire (plus ground) from the house to the pole.  It will have black and red hots.  You could switch the red hot in the house, and run the black hot to the pole where the motion detector can switch it.  Then at the light, connect the red from the house, and the output of the motion detector to the light.

However, you're better off using a home-automation capable light with motion detector and remote.  Some of those will even let you add a chime later if you want to know when there's motion.